# Converting mathematical formula into an programmatic algorithm

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, syntax, language-design, mathematical-optimization

I'm working on converting a mathematical formula into a program. This formula is called as optimal pricing policy for perishable products. I've seen this in an article and it is called Karush-Kuhn-Tucker condition. Somehow I lost all my maths skills and unable to understand the formula explained in that. I'm able to understand how to come up with a solution for getting optimal price but I'm worried that I may not address the condition given in this article. For your reference I'm giving the link [here](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2004/03/832.pdf). If somebody can explain me this Karush-Kuhn-Tucker condition in plain english so that I can think in terms programming language. I'm not interested in the language, i'm ready to implement in any language.

Also giving [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5510/karush-kuhn-tucker-condition-lagrange-multiplier) of question I posted in mathematics stack exchange.

Did anyone come across this kind of situation? How to come up with a programmatic solution for this kind of mathematical formula?

Wiki article for the same is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions)

If there are any already developed libraries for this kind of formula please let me know.

Comment: This optimal pricing policy is used in flight ticket pricing

Comment: If the core of your question is *"If somebody can explain me this Karush-Kuhn-Tucker condition in plain english"*, then you're not really asking a programming question at all, are you? I think sticking with just the math.stackechange.com version is better.

Comment: @dmckee: You are right, that's why I posted it there for plain english, as well as posted here because I asked other questions as well with regards to programming. I'm asking about already developed libraries and how programmers convert mathematical formula to program. So I think it will be a point to ask this question here. I hope I'm clear now.

Comment: An even more appropriate StackExchange site for this question is OR-Exchange http://www.or-exchange.com/  In this case OR stands for Operations Research, much of which deals with mathematical optimization.

Comment: Thanks @Philip Starhill for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a program described by KKT conditions, than you just need a nonlinear solver.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_programming

http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/NLPSolver